# Android estudio

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

buena noche a todos los programadores, es mi primer publicación y esta vez tuve la necesidad de hacerlo ya que en ningún sitio web tengo solución, estoy intentando pasar paramentos de un activity a otro pero con array en android estudio, llenando el array con editText y cuando los paso a mi segunda activity, no manda ningún valor.

```
    public class nueva extends AppCompatActivity {
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.nueva);

        continuar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncontinuar);
        //declarar variables para medidas de acho y largo

        EditText largo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.largo);
        EditText ancho = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ancho);
        //convertir variables edit text a string
        String strlargo = largo.getText().toString();
        String strancho = ancho.getText().toString();
//array donde se guardan los valores de los EditText
        
 String[] datos = new String[]{strlargo, strancho};

//evento para enviar los parametros a otro activity
 continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


              

            Bundle enviaDatos = new Bundle();
            enviaDatos.putStringArray("keyDatos", datos);
            Intent intent = new Intent(nueva.this, elijetono.class);
            intent.putExtras(enviaDatos);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
        });
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para entender cómo funciona SO y de paso leer [ask] para entender cómo elaborar una pregunta correcta. No podemos ayudarte si nos proporcionas solo mitad del código... parece que estás guardando los valores correctamente pero no sabemos cómo los estás leyendo. Por favor añade el código necesario del segundo activity! Por cierto, las clases en Java *SIEMPRE* empiezan en mayúscula :)

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido @Ricardo Warrior antes de todo el putStringArray es para mandar matrizes digamos, lo que te llega a la otra Activity es un String[][] cosa que eso no quieres.

Deberias de hacerlo de esta manera:

Actividad 1:

```
Bundle param=new Bundle();
param.PutSerializable("OBJECT", listado);
```

Actividad 2:

```
item=(List<TuObjeto>)this.Intent.Extras.GetSerializable("OBJECT");
```

con el PutSerializable serializes cualquier objeto hasta un listado tambien y lo pones en el bundle i en la otra actividad lo deserializas.